# How to update embedded document in array in mongoose where operation should be atomic, should update on the latest one and return updated document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Currently working on node.js and MongoDB with mongoose.

```
//Document in mongoDB
{
  name: 'first',
  _id: '1000'
  phases: [{
      _id: 1,
      phaseName: 'phase1',
      stories: [{
          _id: s1,
          sname: 'sfirst'
        },
        {
          _id: s2,
          sname: 'ssecond'
        },
        {
          _id: s3,
          sname: 'sthird'
        }
      ],

    },
    {
      _id: 2,
      phaseName: 'phase2',
      stories: [{
          _id: s1,
          sname: 'sfirst'
        },
        {
          _id: s2,
          sname: 'ssecond'
        },
        {
          _id: s3,
          sname: 'sthird'
        }
      ],

    }
  ],
}
```

All I have is

1. id=1000 (to find this document in mongodb)
2. phaseId=1 and remstoryId=s2 (i.e delete s2 from stories from phase with id 1)
3. phaseId=2, storyId={ _id: s4, sname: fourth}, position: 1 (add story in stories at index 1 in phase 2)

Main requirement is this operation should be

1. Atomic
2. No other user can perform operation on this same document while performing above operation. I mean lock this document.

I can we can do this operation using findOne() and save()

```
Model.findOne({
  id
}, (err, plan) => {
  if (!err) {

    //REMOVE THE STORY FROM PHASE
    const phase = plan.phases.find((phase) => phase._id === delPhaseID);
    phase.stories = phase.stories.filter((story) => story._id !== delStoryId);

    //ADD STORY IN STORIES
    const addPhase = plan.phases.find((phase) => phase._id === addPhaseID);
    addPhase.stories.splice(pos, 0, story);

    //SAVE PLAN
    plan.save((err, doc) => {
       if(!err)
         console.log(doc) // UPDATED DOCUMENT
       });
  }
})
```

but this operation is not atomic as per below image taken from [masteringjs](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/mongoose/update). How can we solve this problem

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `findOneAndUpdate()` with [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/index.html),

- `$pull` to remove in `p1` id's stories is `s1`
- `$push` to specific position for `p2` use [$position](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/position/)
- `new: true` to return updated document

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: "1000" },
    {
        $pull: {
            "phases.$[p1].stories": {
                _id: "s1"
            }
        },
        $push: {
            "phases.$[p2].stories": {
                $each: [{
                    _id: "s4",
                    sname: "fourth"
                }],
                $position: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            { "p1._id": 1 },
            { "p2._id": 2 }
        ],
        new: true
    }
)
```

Comment: Working on it. As soon as it works in my project, I'll accept your answer. BTW learned a lot with your answer especially to use findOneAndUpdate with $push and $pull. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. I wanna know one more thing is there any way in the solution that you gave me that if pull operation fails in some way then the whole operation fails and MongoDB throws error. If not then is there any way to do that.

Comment: 1) You can do it with 2 queries, first pull, of it success then second push, 2) might be you can do it with [update with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/)